# Reinitialize service in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I deployed my service within a self hosted (OWIN) ASP.NET Web API:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new MyHttpControllerTypeResolver());
```

Because of some changes in the underlying system I would like to reinitialize the service (singleton; instance of `MyHttpControllerTypeResolver`). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing how your application is structured, I'll assume the line of code you posted is in a method called `Configuration` belonging to a class called `Startup` (or similar), and that somewhere something is calling `WebApp.Start<Startup>(...)`.

`Configuration` is sort of a "magic" method name that `WebApp.Start` will look for and call. `WebApp.Start` returns an `IDisposible`. In order to re-initialize things, you'll need to capture that `IDisposible` in some variable (let's call it `app`), call `app.Dispose()`, and then call `WebApp.Start` again.